# How do I stop a before_save method from running if a forms field is blank in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method that converts a URL entered/pasted into a micropost form by a user. The URL they enter or paste is converted in an appropriate URL before the micropost is posted/saved. I can then use for some other things in my APP.

The thing is I only need the before_save method to run if a link has been entered / pasted. When no link is entered or pasted a few things in my app break. I would like to know what the appropriate conditional statement to use would be? and possible an example..

**Here is my model..**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    include OgpObjectsHelper

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
    has_one  :photo, :dependent => :destroy


    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, 
    :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }, 
    :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessor :username 
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :poster_id, :username, :link, :photo_attributes 


    validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 10000 }
    validates :user_id, :presence => true

    default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'

    auto_strip_attributes :content,
                          :nullify => true, 
                          :strip => false

    before_save :clean_up_video_link

    protected

    def clean_up_video_link
      self.link = get_video_data(link)
    end

end
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, that's what you can use

```
def clean_up_video_link
  link = get_video_data(link) if link?
end
```

Comment: If link was the first thing I tried but I forgot the question mark. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `if link.present?`?

Comment: @d11wtq it's the same, but `link?` looks cleaner in my ([and not only my](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/56-use-query-attribute)) opinion.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Must be an ActiveRecord thing (I don't use AR) ;)